# Dell Dimension 5100, Faulty PSU, replacing it with generic brand

Tags: power-supply, dell-dimension

The power button on my Dell Dimension 5100 started flashing yellow a couple of days ago. Upon further investigation I opened the computer and found a AUX PWR led glowing in yellow. I'm taking a chance on believing that the PSU is faulty and that I need to get a replacement.

The Dell Dimension 5100 are supposedly using nonstandard DELL PSU and uses ATX type PSU.

1) What I'm wondering, can I replace the PSU with a better PSU from [Chieftech](http://www.chieftec.eu/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=470&Itemid=715)?

2) I'm worried about the fan position on the PSU that I've investigated. The Dell PSU has the fan on the back while the Chieftech one ejects the heat to the left.

3) Another thing I don't seem to find out is if the wires/cables in the new PSU will be long enough to fit in the old computer?

4) Will it be a problem for the motherboard that put a larger PSU in the computer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A steady amber power light could mean another piece of hardware has failed, not the PSU, better to diagnose it first, then spend $$

See this troubleshooting guide for your 5100 (See System Lights, and Diagnostic lights)

http://support.dell.com/support/edocs/systems/dim5100/en/sm/tshoot1.htm#wp1122208

2. You need to install a PSU compatible with that model, Dell uses that rear fan to pull heat out of the case, very important. Just because the fan is on the side does not mean it is not exausting (pushing) the heat out the back of the PSU. You need to investigate this further.
3. No

Comment: No, the power button light is flashing amber on the console. On the inside motherboard a steady amber light says aux power.

Answer (score 1):

Dell uses proprietary parts, including PSU's, so you would have a *very* hard time finding a generic brand replacement.  Assuming that's what you need, you can find one on eBay for ~$30.

Comment: yes, but for that particular model they use ATX type PSU

Comment: You can use a standard ATX PSU in the 5100, Some slightly older Dells (ex 8400) had to have the rear panel modified due to original PSU's did not have the rocker switch and the power socket was located in a different place.

Here is a good source for Dell and other OEM PSU's, guaranteed to fit and work, here are the 3 options for the 5100

http://www.power-on.com/oemupgrade.html

.

Some really old Dells did have a non standard PSU, the 20 pin connector was wired differently and a standard PSU would fry the motherboard if connected and powered up.